# JPA seems to force cyclic dependencies between packages

Tags: hibernate, jpa

The way JPA manages dependencies kind of drives me nuts. If I have an entity Parent and I want to have another entity Child that is cleaned up when a Parent is deleted then it seems I have to have a hardcoded dependency going both ways. This wreaks havoc on how I would like to layout my packages.

For example, consider I have an entity called User. Later, I want to add Facebook capabilities. So I want to add the Facebook token and id for users. I create a Facebook package to contain all my facebook specific plug-in code. My FacebookInfo entity contains the User entity reference. But now I have a problem. I want to have the FacebookInfo records deleted when a User is deleted. This forces me to add a FacebookInfo reference to User creating a bidirectional relationship. And BAM, now I have a cycle between my "user" and "facebook" packages. I don't need FacebookInfo in User for any reason other than to support a cascaded delete. Ideally, I would want the FacebookInfo entity class to specify that it wants to be deleted when a User is. Then all the dependencies go one way.

Do most people punt on cyclic dependencies in packages when using JPA or is there a decent way to avoid this? If there is a hibernate-specific way to deal with this (without using XML) I can also do that. Thanks.

Comment: Using a bidirectional relationship just allows JPA of knowing that User has Facebook entities that need to be deleted.  If you don't want the reference, then you need some other way to tell it there are facebook entities that need to be removed.  Events are one way, application knowledge another. Ie your removeUser method could query for facebook related entities and remove them as well as call remove for the user.  Or use JPQL bulk delete.  Or use preRemove events, putting the dependency in a different class/package.  With JPA 2.1, entity listeners can use CDI

Comment: Sure, I can roll my own and that is probably what I will do. Just seems weird that JPA saw fit to reverse the ON DELETE dependency in SQL. They put it on the dependent table for a reason. Sometimes I wish JPA hadn't tried so hard to abstract away the object-relational impedance mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do most people punt on cyclic dependencies in packages when using JPA[?]

In my experience: Not only when using JPA. Which is one of the many things that makes many large code bases so horrid.

> Is there a decent way to avoid this?

The basic idea is to use interfaces and I see two options to apply it. One using JPA, but I can't promise it works. The other more or less independent of JPA.

**The JPA way**

Instead of referencing back to `FacebookInfo` reference back to an interface `ExtraUserInfo`, then let `FacebookInfo` implement that interface (or abstract class). `ExtraUserInfo` will live in the same package as the user, so gone are all the cycles. I'm not sure if such a mapping based on interfaces is feasible, but if it works it should have the desired effect.

**JPA independent**

You can create a mechanism where before a delete (or any other relevant action) a `Listener` gets informed. Again the `Listener` interface and the whole mechanism would reside in the `User` package (or more likely in a package the `User` package depends on), while the actual implementation of the `Listener` would reside in the `UserInfo` package. Depending on your architecture there might be various places to establish such a notification mechanism. Possibly in repositories located in the persistance layer. Actually I think JPA supports such a notification mechanism itself, so this might turn into an alternative JPA base solution.

Comment: I'm not aware of how I can reference the entity as an interface. Really, User shouldn't even need to know that people "extend" it. JPA basically forces tables to be modified when they are extended with new relationships. Your second suggestion is probably what I will end up doing. I can autowire these in User so that FacebookInfoDeleteListener can just implement the UserDeleteListener interface. Thanks! Still don't understand why JPA did not allow ON DELETE specification on the dependent entity. Weird.